# talking button won't work

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

My app has `Buttons` and when you press the `Buttons` they use text to speech to say something.

My `Buttons` work fine, but when I set up the `id.talk` `Button` and gave it the speech command it didn't do anything. When I click on it nothing happens.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {

    // use switch case so each button does a different thing
    // accurately(similar to an if statement)
    case R.id.btn_speak:
        String words1 = speakButton.getText().toString();

        // speakwords(xxxx); is the piece of code that actually calls the
        // text to speech
        speakWords(words1);
        Intent voiceIntent = new Intent(
                "android.intent.action.RECOGNITIONMENU");
        startActivity(voiceIntent);
        break;
    case R.id.aboutbutton:
        String words2 = infoButton.getText().toString();
        speakWords(words2);
        Intent infoIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.INFOSCREEN");
        startActivity(infoIntent);
        break;
    case R.id.voicebutton:
        speakWords("Speak Now");
        startVoiceRecognitionActivity(); // call for voice recognition
                                            // activity
        break;
    case R.id.talk:
        speakWords("This is the main menu.");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please try stepping through this to see what is actually going on. Try putting `Log` output inside the `case R.id.talk` and see if the `Log` is displayed when you press the `Button`. Let us know the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
btn =(Button) findViewById(R.id.talk);
                                ^^^^

btn.setOnClickListener(this);<---
```

have you added listener to your new button ?

Comment: Holy CRAP I feel stupid. I must have messed around with my code for a half hour and I missed something as simple as my listener.

Answer (score 0):

**Please check that have you registered your button with the OnClickListener**

**Eg:**

```
 mbutt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.talk);
   mbutt.setOnclickListener(this);
```